# Dynamic Linq - query a schema that is only known at run time?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I know with dynamic linq you can construct expressions dynamically in the same way that you might build and execute a dynamic SQL statement - e.g. a dynamic where clause or a dynamic select list. Is it possible to do this in cases where the schema is not known at compile time?

In a database I'm working with users can define their own entities which causes new tables/columns to be created in the back-end database.  At run time I'll know the table & column names I need to work with but I won't know the schema at compile time hence I can't build a DBML to work with up front.

Is there any facility for the dynamic discovery of the schema at run time or is this a case where I need to stick with building dynamic SQL statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we understand, you don't know neither schema name nor the full structure of your schema for sure.
In this case it seems that the [strongly-typed ExecuteQuery method overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx)  will be an option.
Just write the SQL queries and add the necessary parameters (like table and column names) either using string concatenation or as parameters.

Comment: Might be an option - I'll give this a try next week and see how it works out.  Thanks.